# Full-Text Search in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, full-text-search

I followed the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter) and it's almost work well but when I use Full-text Search i got an error:

```
Unsupported lookup 'search' for CharField or join on the field not permitted
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Need some code of the viewset.

Comment: Oh I received a notification that SearchFilter docs for full-text search are outdated. I don't know if there's any other way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As reported in the DRF Search Filter documentations:

> *"The SearchFilter class supports simple single query parameter based searching, and is based on the Django admin's search functionality."*

So if you want to implement a complete [Full-text Search with Django and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/full-text-search+django+postgresql) you can read the official documentation about the [full-text search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/postgres/search/).

If you are interested about external article about that here it's one I wrote:
[Full-Text Search in Django with PostgreSQL](https://www.paulox.net/2017/12/22/full-text-search-in-django-with-postgresql/)

Comment: Okay ! I will try it. Thank you so much ^^

Comment: @phuc-nguyen If you think my answer helped you can vote and select it. Thanks.

Comment: What index is needed when using DRF `SearchFilter` ? I cant seem to find the right one. I've tried using Gin index but upon manually querying the one being used by `SearchFilter` it is still being retrieved via Sequential Scan. Any ideas on this?